# Why can't argument be forwarded inside lambda without mutable?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, language-lawyer

In the below program, when `mutable` is not used, the program fails to compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <functional>

std::queue<std::function<void()>> q;

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void enqueue(T&& func, Args&&... args)
{
    //q.emplace([=]() {                  // this fails
    q.emplace([=]() mutable {             //this works
        func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    });
}

int main()
{
    auto f1 = [](int a, int b) { std::cout << a << b << "\n"; };
    auto f2 = [](double a, double b) { std::cout << a << b << "\n";};
    enqueue(f1, 10, 20);
    enqueue(f2, 3.14, 2.14);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the compiler error

```
lmbfwd.cpp: In instantiation of ‘enqueue(T&&, Args&& ...)::<lambda()> [with T = main()::<lambda(int, int)>&; Args = {int, int}]’:
lmbfwd.cpp:11:27:   required from ‘struct enqueue(T&&, Args&& ...) [with T = main()::<lambda(int, int)>&; Args = {int, int}]::<lambda()>’
lmbfwd.cpp:10:2:   required from ‘void enqueue(T&&, Args&& ...) [with T = main()::<lambda(int, int)>&; Args = {int, int}]’
lmbfwd.cpp:18:20:   required from here
lmbfwd.cpp:11:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘forward<int>(const int&)’
   func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

I am not able to understand why argument forwarding fails without `mutable`.

Besides, if I pass a lambda with string as argument, `mutable` is not required and program works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <functional>

std::queue<std::function<void()>> q;

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void enqueue(T&& func, Args&&... args)
{
   //works without mutable
    q.emplace([=]() {
        func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    });
}
void dequeue()
{
    while (!q.empty()) {
        auto f = std::move(q.front());
        q.pop();
        f();
    }
}
int main()
{
    auto f3 = [](std::string s) { std::cout << s << "\n"; };
    enqueue(f3, "Hello");
    dequeue();
    return 0;
}
```

Why is mutable required in case of `int double` and not in case of `string` ? What is the difference between these two ?

Comment: As an aside, in the second example you are not forwarding `std::string`, you are forwarding `const char*`. It doesn't matter what type the function takes, but what type arguments are passed to `enqueue`. My guess is, the argument being `const` from the start somehow makes a difference, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: And indeed, [it does fail](https://rextester.com/WFBR88390) if you make it `enqueue(f3, std::string("Hello"));`

Comment: ...yes, or `"Hello"s` (using string literals)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The direction is right: if you pass a `const` argument, the error disappears. See for example https://godbolt.org/z/EdY4Mn where I just introduced some empty class `Foo`. If you remove the constness of `Foo`, it fails to compile. Still not sure why, though...

Comment: It may be enlightening (although pointless) to realize that using `std::forward<const Args>` also fixes the compile error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A non-`mutable` lambda generates a *closure type* with an implicit `const` qualifier on its `operator()` overload.

`std::forward` is a conditional move: it is equivalent to `std::move` when the provided template argument is not an *lvalue reference*. It is defined as follows:

```
template< class T >
constexpr T&& forward( typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& t ) noexcept;

template< class T >
constexpr T&& forward( typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& t ) noexcept;
```

(See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward).

---

Let's simplify your snippet to:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void enqueue(T&& func, Args&&... args)
{
    [=] { func(std::forward<Args>(args)...); };
}

int main()
{
    enqueue([](int) {}, 10);
}
```

The error produced by `clang++ 8.x` is:

> ```
> error: no matching function for call to 'forward'
>     [=] { func(std::forward<Args>(args)...); };
>                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'enqueue<(lambda at wtf.cpp:11:13), int>' requested here
>     enqueue([](int) {}, 10);
>     ^
> note: candidate function template not viable: 1st argument ('const int')
>       would lose const qualifier
>     forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type& __t) noexcept
>     ^
> note: candidate function template not viable: 1st argument ('const int')
>       would lose const qualifier
>     forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&& __t) noexcept
>     ^
> ```

In the snippet above:

- `Args` is `int` and refers to the type outside of the lambda.
- `args` refers to the member of the closure synthesized via lambda capture, and is `const` due to the lack of `mutable`.

Therefore the `std::forward` invocation is...

```
std::forward<int>(/* `const int&` member of closure */)
```

...which doesn't match any existing overload of `std::forward`. There is a mismatch between the template argument provided to `forward` and its function argument type.

Adding `mutable` to the lambda makes `args` non-`const`, and a suitable `forward` overload is found (the first one, which moves its argument).

---

By using C++20 pack-expansion captures to "rewrite" the name of `args`, we can avoid the mismatch mentioned above, making the code compile even without `mutable`:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
void enqueue(T&& func, Args&&... args)
{
    [func, ...xs = args] { func(std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)...); };
}
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zp4ize)

---

> Why is `mutable` required in case of `int double` and not in case of `string` ? What is the difference between these two ?

This is a fun one - it works because you're not actually passing a `std::string` in your invocation:

```
enqueue(f3, "Hello");
//          ^~~~~~~
//          const char*
```

If you correctly match the type of the argument passed to `enqueue` to the one accepted by `f3`, it will stop working as expected (unless you use `mutable` or C++20 features):

```
enqueue(f3, std::string{"Hello"});
// Compile-time error.
```

---

To explain why the version with `const char*` works, let's again look at a simplified example:

```
template <typename T>
void enqueue(T&& func, const char (&arg)[6])
{
    [=] { func(std::forward<const char*>(arg)); };
}

int main()
{
    enqueue([](std::string) {}, "Hello");
}
```

`Args` is deduced as `const char(&)[6]`. There is a matching `forward` overload:

```
template< class T >
constexpr T&& forward( typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& t ) noexcept;
```

After substitution:

```
template< class T >
constexpr const char*&& forward( const char*&& t ) noexcept;
```

This simply returns `t`, which is then used to construct the `std::string`.

Comment: Wow, that's an excellent answer! Can you perhaps add some references to the stardard?

Comment: @andreee: improved my answer, let me know if it is clear.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have a doubt, in case of const char *, we also have a const args.. still it works.. why is that ?

Comment: @bornfree: added an explanation.

Comment: Where does `const char*` come from? He's passing around a reference so `Args` is `const char(&)[6]` so it's `std::forward<const char(&)[6]>(arg)`.

Comment: Your code snipped is not move friendly. It incorrectly copies the parameters, even if a move is possible. A forward is also needed, when initializing the captures.